# Simultaneously iterating through multiple "lists" in LaTeX

Tags: list, loops, command, latex, pgf

The `pgffor` package in LaTeX allows for looping through commands which contain "listlike" information. As mentioned in section 88 of the `pgf` [manual](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), the `pgffor` package also allows for iterating simultaneously through two sets of "listlike" information, a bit like `python`'s `zip` function. Here's an example of this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\iterable{
  item1/description1,
  item2/description2,
  item3/description3}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
  \foreach \i/\q in \iterable{
    \noindent \i \q\\
  }
\end{document}
```

The above will iterate simultaneously through items in `\iterable` separated by a forward slash character `/`. However, if I have a high number of different "lists", then maintaining them all within the `\iterable` command could prove difficult.

Does `pgffor` allow for a way in which to separate the iterable items into different commands such that I can better keep track of the items that need to get iterated over? For example:

```
\newcommand\iterable1{item1,item2,item3}
\newcommand\iterable2{description1, description2, description3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the fastest solution, but you could iterate over both list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\iterablea{item1,item2,item3}
\newcommand\iterableb{description1, description2, description3}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
  \foreach \i [count=\xi] in \iterablea {
  \foreach \q [count=\xq] in \iterableb {
    \ifnum\xi=\xq
      \noindent \i{} \q\par
    \fi
  }}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very efficient. It makes use of a nested for loop and iterates more times than needed.